# Javascript Popup Focus?

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

Forgive me as I am not a programmer and don't understand a ton about this.

I have tried searching but can't seem to find the problem I am having.

So I have a really simple pop up using Javascript:

```
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(
url,'popUpWindow3','height=500,width=900,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
}
```

Which I call on with:

```
onclick="JavaScript:newPopup('images/product-<?php echo $pro['id'];?>.jpg');">
```

It works well except if they click for the pop up and return to the page the next click updates the first pop up window and the user must find the window that contains the image they selected. If they had closed the window it will re appear in the foreground but if they return to the main site without closing the window the content updates in the background.

I want the pop-up window to come back into the foreground when someone clicks it, regardless.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Thank you so much in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(
url,'popUpWindow3','height=500,width=900,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
popupWindow.focus();
}
```

add a .focus on the window and you should be fine.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! lol I will never get over how simple the solution to some really annoying problems is when you deal with the web.